# Running a script on starting Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

How can I run this script https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ when Joomla starts?

I tried to make a code like :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/theme2029/style.css" media="screen">


<audio id="radio" preload="true">
    <source src="http://sc8.1.fm:8030/;" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<div id="player" >

    <div class="top-wrapper">
        <div class="top-part" id="leftsp"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/speaker.png"></div>
        <div class="top-part" id="logo-fm"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="top-part" id="rightsp"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/speaker.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-wrapper">
        <div class="down-part" id=sound><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/soundbx.png">
            <div id="vol-stat"></div>
            <div id="pointer"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/soundp.png" id="rol"></div>
            <div id="volup"><button id="plus" disabled onclick="document.getElementById('radio').volume+=0.25"></button></div>
            <div id="voldon"><button id="min" disabled onclick="document.getElementById('radio').volume-=0.25"></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="down-part" id="playbx"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/playCirc.png">
            <div><button id="run" class="contbtn"></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="down-part" id="tune"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/tunebx.png" id="tunebg">
            <div id="chonp"><img src="templates/theme2029/imgs/tunep.png" id="channelp"></div>
            <div class="tunedon" id="changtune"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<script src="<?php echo JURI::base().'templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jQueryRotate.js'; ?>"></script>
```

i got in inspecting element this message :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

What that mean and what i have to do to add this lib. into index of my joomla

Comment: What does this actually produce in your output html page <script src="<?php echo JURI::base().'templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jQueryRotate.js'; ?>"></script>

Comment: it does nothing ,, no function work and when i press the play button i got in inspecting element the 403 msg

Comment: Well if that code ends up with a `<script  src=""` then that's your problem so fix that.  Nothing to do with Joomla or javascript, you have a php error.

Comment: no the code above will be in the header section and it will end on the header section ,,, the issue is it wont import this lib, https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate ,,,

Comment: Do you have ownership of that file?

Comment: yes i have ... ok guys let me ask the question in another way ,, i have this block of code and i want insert it inside the header of my joomla theme with external jquery/js library,, how i do it ??